# Problem on overstay regarding the new law that would start on the 12th of August in Thailand

Tags: health, international-travel, thailand, stopovers, overstaying

I am a teacher in the North. I have a friend who also is a teacher; he is having an overstay issue because he was very sick so he could not go to Malaysia after he finished to sign the contract to teach. He is welling to pay the charges on overstay but he is afraid about the new law that was just implemented on overstay in Thailand.  If it has already been put in place or it will be put in place only on August 12th. We want to know if there is any possibility to travel to Malaysia within this period - that is before august 12 - to get a non b. Is it possible? Please we need your help. We know overstay is against the law but there are situations you can not control them by yourself it is natural. We will be very grateful to have a solution towards the issue at hand and how can we go about it without any problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What will happen if I overstay in Thailand with an expired passport but get a new passport months later?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/33671/what-will-happen-if-i-overstay-in-thailand-with-an-expired-passport-but-get-a-ne) Also not quite sure what exactly your question is. Could you structure your question better, so that we can understand what exactly your question is?

Answer (score 1):

The only folks who can accurately answer your question regarding any new laws would be the Immigration Office.  With the military government's push towards following the rule of law it is hard to guess how strict immigration will be from here forward.

Your friend might wish to prepare by documenting his illness, bills or invoices from the hospital, a letter from his physician explaining the illness and advice not to travel.  If he can document why he overstayed, he might find leniency when applying for his next Non-Imm B.

Comment: The friend's embassy may also be able to help.